# Matching filename and saving it to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does anyone know how to match a filename and then saving it to a variable?

For instance I've got multiple files that are being saved in one folder. All of them start with the same name. "AmountFile" all of them start with but then they differ in filename rest of the filename is date.

So all look like AmountFile in the begining but then AmountFile20141020 and so on.

I want to match the filename save it in a variable so I can use it in a os.rename function.

```
File1 = AmountFile123
File2 = AmountFile321
File3 = AmountFile456
File4 = AmountFile789
```

I want to match them so I can use it in a variable.

```
def main():
d = 'D:\Applications\IMP\Something'
for filename in os.listdir(d):
    title = 'Import_ABC'
    oldFile = 'AmountFile'
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        os.rename(oldFile,title+".csv")

main()

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

My system will when finished rename files in the folder automatically move them to another folder from where they will be imported to our database. Problem is as in the example files have the same start but end differently which is making it hard to run the function. For the OldFile variable I need to match a file name which can be saved instead of 'AmountFile'

Comment: Er, what? `filename = "AmountFile"`?

Comment: But thats not exactly true since the file name is AmountFile123 and then there are AmountFile345674 etc so it varies all the time. But they have the same prefix

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? Could you explain an entire test process - show how would set up the program to test it, and what result you would expect? Do you just want a list of all the matching files?

Comment: So, are you asking for code to scan a directory and find the common prefix of the files within it?

Comment: I've edited my question hopefully its clearer now :) I want to scan filenames save it in a varible. In SQL you do IF filename like '%AmountFile%' Begin.. I want to do the same thing in python

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob

filenames = glob.glob("AmountFile*")
```

`filenames` will then be a list of all files in the current directory whose names start with `AmountFile`.